# dotnet-dump not creating a file on macOS

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and a .NET core app.

I've noticed a memory leak and attempted to use [`dotnet-dump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump) to get details of the leak, however on running `dotnet-dump collect --process-id 6107`, I see the following:

```
Writing full to /Users/xxx/core_20210216_205737
Complete
```

However nothing is in that location.

Has anyone faced this issue - any help appreciated.

And `dotnet list --sdks` shows:

```
3.1.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.406 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.103 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Also the same issue on Alpine Linux in K8s. Reinstalling the SDK did not helped. Day before it worked just fine.

Comment: Got a similar issue, you have managed to get it solved?

Comment: I ended up using a Windows machine to get the dump